# How to solve bundle install fail due to linking failure of sassc/libsass.so

Tags: ruby, activeadmin, manjaro

`bundle install` is failing on Manjaro Linux due to linking failure of sassc/libsass.so, which is in the dependency tree of the activeadmin.

**Full error report:**

```
compiling ./libsass/src/sass2scss.cpp
linking shared-object sassc/libsass.so
g++: fatal error: cannot execute ‘lto1’: execvp: Não é um diretório
compilation terminated.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: g++ returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: erro: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:259: libsass.so] Erro 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/mateus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sassc-2.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/mateus/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/sassc-2.2.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sassc (2.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sassc -v '2.2.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.                                                                                

In Gemfile:
  activeadmin was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
    sassc-rails was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
      sassc
```

**Specs:**
Kernel Version: 5.4.18-1-MANJARO
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0):

Manjaro is not shipped with `base-devel`, which is needed to compile the dependencies of `sassc`. To install `base-devel` run:

```
pacman -S base-devel
```

And then `bundle install` again.

About: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Installation_Guide&diff=253744&oldid=250715